# Opening several URLs in same tab one by one using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my script where a JSON file contains all the URLs to be opened.
What this script does is, it opens a URL takes screenshot and closes it; then opens a new one and so on.

What if I want to keep using the same browser session for all these URLs. Like Go to site 1, take screen cap. Now go to site 2 in the same browser/tab. and close the session/browser only at the last URL.

```
import json
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

with open('path to json file', encoding='utf-8') as s:
    data = json.loads(s.read())

for site in data['sites']:
    driver = Chrome('path to chrome driver')
    driver.get(data['sites'][site])
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(site + '.png')
    driver.close()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its because you are closing the browser every time loop ends , you just need to keep `driver.close()` outside the loop.

```
import json
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

with open('path to json file', encoding='utf-8') as s:
    data = json.loads(s.read())

for site in data['sites']:
    driver = Chrome('path to chrome driver')
    driver.get(data['sites'][site])
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(site + '.png')
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Then don't open / close the browser for each link, do it once:

```
driver = Chrome('path to chrome driver')
for site in data['sites']:
    driver.get(data['sites'][site])
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file(site + '.png')
driver.close()
```